# Unable to Disable `colr` Feature With HarfBuzz Renderer From the `fontspec` Package

Tags: color, luatex, fontspec, arabic, harfbuzz

I noticed that if you use the `Renderer = HarfBuzz` fontspec option, the `colr` OpenType feature automatically gets disabled. If you use the default renderer, the feature does not get enabled but you can manually enable/disable it. My problem is that I cannot disable the `colr` feature if I use the HarfBuzz renderer. I cannot use XeLaTeX instead of LuaLaTeX or the default renderer instead of HarfBuzz as a workaround, because those are needed for the font I am using, which can be obtained [here](https://digitalkhatt.org/about#opentype).

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bidi = basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[main, import]{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}[Renderer = HarfBuzz, RawFeature = -colr]{digitalkhatt.otf}

\newcommand\ayah{^^^^06dd}

\begin{document}

بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ~\ayah١
ٱلْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ ٱلْعَٰلَمِينَ~\ayah٢
ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ~\ayah٣
مَٰلِكِ يَوْمِ ٱلدِّينِ~\ayah٤
إِيَّاكَ نَعْبُدُ وَإِيَّاكَ نَسْتَعِينُ~\ayah٥
ٱهْدِنَا ٱلصِّرَٰطَ ٱلْمُسْتَقِيمَ~\ayah٦
صِرَٰطَ ٱلَّذِينَ أَنْعَمْتَ عَلَيْهِمْ غَيْرِ ٱلْمَغْضُوبِ عَلَيْهِمْ وَلَا ٱلضَّآلِّينَ~\ayah٧

\end{document}
```

[image]

I expected the end-of-ayah symbols in the above image to be black, but they are coloured.

Comment: For clarification: what do you want the output to look like, how should it be different from the output that you currently have?

Comment: The end-of-ayah symbols should be black, they shouldn't be coloured.

Comment: I edited my question to make that clear.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but a COLR table is not an OpenType feature. I think, this font does not have a feature that enables you to switch on and off the colored glyphs.

Comment: Makes sense, but why can I freely enable/disable `colr` when using the default `Node` renderer? To me it seems like this is a problem with HarfBuzz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `RawFeature ={colr=1}` to activate `colr` font feature, and to deactivate the feature just replace `1` with any other integer.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bidi = basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[main, import]{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}[Renderer = HarfBuzz, RawFeature ={colr=2}]{digitalkhatt.otf} %  RawFeature ={colr=3}
\newcommand\ayah{^^^^06dd}

\begin{document}

بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ~\ayah١
ٱلْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ ٱلْعَٰلَمِينَ~\ayah٢
ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ~\ayah٣
مَٰلِكِ يَوْمِ ٱلدِّينِ~\ayah٤
إِيَّاكَ نَعْبُدُ وَإِيَّاكَ نَسْتَعِينُ~\ayah٥
ٱهْدِنَا ٱلصِّرَٰطَ ٱلْمُسْتَقِيمَ~\ayah٦
صِرَٰطَ ٱلَّذِينَ أَنْعَمْتَ عَلَيْهِمْ غَيْرِ ٱلْمَغْضُوبِ عَلَيْهِمْ وَلَا ٱلضَّآلِّينَ~\ayah٧


\addfontfeatures{ RawFeature ={colr=1}} % to activate colr feature


بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ~\ayah١
ٱلْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ ٱلْعَٰلَمِينَ~\ayah٢
ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ~\ayah٣
مَٰلِكِ يَوْمِ ٱلدِّينِ~\ayah٤
إِيَّاكَ نَعْبُدُ وَإِيَّاكَ نَسْتَعِينُ~\ayah٥
ٱهْدِنَا ٱلصِّرَٰطَ ٱلْمُسْتَقِيمَ~\ayah٦
صِرَٰطَ ٱلَّذِينَ أَنْعَمْتَ عَلَيْهِمْ غَيْرِ ٱلْمَغْضُوبِ عَلَيْهِمْ وَلَا ٱلضَّآلِّينَ~\ayah٧


\end{document}
```

[image]